# How do I lowercase the contents of ALL string variables?

Tags: string, stata, lowercase

I'm trying to figure out an efficient way to lowercase all of the contents of string variables in Stata. I know how to do it one variable at a time (using example of a variable called VARIABLE), like

```
replace VARIABLE = lower(VARIABLE)
```

Is there a way to do it simply, such as using the following to lowercase all variable names:

```
rename *, lower
```

Answer (score 3):

`ds` will give you a list of names of all string variables after which you can just loop over them in the usual way. See also `findname` (*Stata Journal*) for an alternative command to find names of variables satisfying certain conditions. The syntax using `findname` would be similar, `findname, type(string)`.

```
ds, has(type string) 
foreach v in `r(varlist)' { 
    replace `v' = lower(`v') 
}
```